# How to use .collect() on each iterator returned by .unzip()?

Tags: rust

I have the following code, in which `fac` return `(MyType, OtherType)`:

```
let l = (-1..13).map(|x| {
    fac(x).0
}).collect::<Vec<MyType>>();
```

It works, but I'm throwing away the `OtherType` values. So I decided to use `.unzip`, like this:

```
let (v, r) = (-1..13).map(|x| {
    fac(x)
}).unzip();
let l = v.collect::<Vec<MyType>>();
let q = r.collect::<Vec<OtherType>>();
```

But type inference fails with:

```
error: the type of this value must be known in this context
let l = v.collect::<Vec<Literal>>();
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
let q = r.collect::<Vec<OtherType>>();
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The thing is: I don't know or care what is the concrete type of the iterators (and I would suppose the compiler could infer them, as shown in the first snippet). How to satisfy the compiler in this case?

Also, I would prefer to restructure the code - I don't like to separately call `.collect()` on both `v` and `r`. Ideally I would continue the method chain after `.unzip()`, returning two `Vec`s in that expression.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`.unzip()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.unzip) doesn't return iterators — it acts like two parallel collect! You can in fact collect the two pieces to different kinds of collections, but let's use vectors for both in this example:

```
// Give a type hint to determine the collection type
let (v, r): (Vec<MyType>, Vec<OtherType>) = (-1..13).map(|x| {
    fac(x)
}).unzip();
```

It is done this way to be as simple and transparent as possible. Returning two iterators instead would need them to share a common state, a complexity that rust's iterator library prefers to avoid.

Comment: That's too bad, I actually need to call further iterator methods on `r` (specifically a fold). I suppose I can just call `.into_iter()` on that `r`, but I wanted to avoid allocating an intermediate structure.

Comment: Only way to avoid that would be to `.fold()` on the tupled iterator. Imagine if unzip returned two iterators, their hidden shared state would have to allocate and buffer anyway, if you just consume one of the parts. And if you consume them in lockstep, then you might as well loop or fold over them together in one iterator.

Comment: So I need to do everything, then call `.unzip` in the end. That's not too bad :) thanks!